# Revival badge can be gained by down voting the *real* first answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revival-badge

I'm not sure if this might be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but I just got the Revival badge by downvoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643841/94197) that already had 2 votes.

My own answer was already on 2 votes, I was revisiting it and wondered why I'd never down voted the accepted answer before— it's completely irrelevant to the question, even though it was accepted.  Several minutes after down voting the accepted answer, I received the revival badge since my answer was the only one with a score of at least 2.

This could technically be seen as gaming, I suppose.  With the right SE data query, I could go through every question with a +2 answer 30 days younger than the question that has an older +2 answer and down vote it, potentially giving the newer answer the Revival badge. It's even possible for several answers to receive the Revival badge for the same question, if users sequentially post answers that are up voted to 2 after down voting previously posted answers.  Unlikely scenarios, I know, but still...

Comment: This wasn't intended I'm sure, but actually querying for the timelines of posts to compare for scores at different intervals (crawling vote history vs observing the current score) is **immensely ** more complex as well.  Perhaps we could find a way to exclude posts you voted down on from counting?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [timeline of that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1629462/timeline) this is what I see.

```
Date                   Your answer        The other answer
January    3, 2010                              +1
January    7, 2010         +1
September 17, 2011         +1                   +1
March      8, 2012         +1                   −2
```

The description given in [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for the badge is the following one:

> Answer a question 30 days after it is asked and have that answer be the first one for that question to reach a score of two.

If "be the first one for that question to reach a score of two" is referring to all the answers given, then the badge should have been eventually given right after September, 2011; in this case, it seems the badge has been assigned after the other answer has been down-voted, after almost 6 months.
"Be the first one to reach a score of two" doesn't imply to keep that score, but I imagine it makes sense not to assign the badge 30 seconds after the answer reached +2. At the same time, I would not expect it to be assigned because a down-vote given after 6 months.

Comment: The other answer reached +2 before my own answer did making it the first as defined by the badge requirements.  The badge award itself will probably be part of a batch process that searches all answers on the site for those matching the criteria that don't already have the badge awarded.  As @NickCraver said in the question comments, the query would have to be extremely complex if it were to check the order of up and down votes as part of that criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your and Robert Love's reputation for 17 September 2011 and when mousehovering above the upvote I can see that both upvotes happened at 19:32:21Z meaning *at the exact same second*! I assume this tie for the second upvote is what confused the badge process and is why it somehow delayed its decision about the badge. Perhaps it's a bug, but I doubt this situation happens very often at all.