# Revival badges awarded for two answers to the same question

Tags: bug, badges, revival-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revival badge can be gained by down voting the *real* first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124983/revival-badge-can-be-gained-by-down-voting-the-real-first-answer)

The description of the Revival badge (*"Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more"*) indicates that -- contrary to the Necromancer badge -- only one answer to a specific question may earn the badge. However, at tex.sx, Revival badges have been awarded to the answers of users Vairis *and* Heiko Oberdiek ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/62/revival)) to the question [Hyperlinking a drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56802/hyperlinking-a-drawing):

[image]

From the comment of Nick Craver to [Revival badge can be gained by down voting the *real* first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124983/revival-badge-can-be-gained-by-down-voting-the-real-first-answer), I gather that the "wrong" answer may earn the Revival badge in some situations, and that complex queries would be necessary to avoid this. But perhaps it is more simple to avoid awarding the badge for several answers to the same question.

Comment: @Jim The linked question (I provided the link) is about the "false" answer receiving a Revival badge, not about *two* answers to the same question receiving it.