# Revival Badge awarded incorrectly when other answer downvoted

Tags: support, down-votes, revival-badge

I've just been awarded the revival badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12590328/431891).

I didn't deserve the badge according to its description, which reads:

```
Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more.
This badge can be awarded multiple times.
```

My answer was not the first answer to score two upvotes.  The accepted answer earned two upvotes before my answer.

Today, as I took another look at the question, I realised that the accepted answer was in fact wrong, so I downvoted it, reducing its score to one.  This left my answer as the only answer *currently* having two or points, and I was then awarded the badge.

Is this behavior intended? If so, then the description of the badge might need reworking.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124983/153741

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem like a bug. When you posted your answer, the other answer had a score of 1, it went up to 2 (so you didn't get the badge back then), now it is down to 1 again and your answer is the only one left with a score of 2 (so you got the badge).

[Badge rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) are:

- Provide an answer to a question that is at least 30 days old at the time of answering.
- Your answer reaches a score of two.
- No other answers posted earlier than your answer have a score of two. "Earlier" refers to the time the answer was originally posted (first revision).

Comment: Not seen those rules before. Very useful.  But in order to be consistent with the short description, I think that third bullet point should be reworded to: "No other answers posted earlier than your answer HAS EVER REACHED a score of two.  After all, the accepted answer was the first to REACH two points, even if it no longer has them.

Comment: In case the 'HAS EVER REACHED' rules is used then it will be a bug and you should not have received the badge. The rule is checking the current score of all answer, I think.

Comment: Yes @Aziz, that is what seems to be happening. The algorithm as it stands is correctly honoring the three bullet points, no argument there! But there's no way that my answer could be described as the "first answer scoring two".  Seems to me that either the short description should change, or the algorithm (and bullet points) should be "fixed". :)

Comment: I agree on that.

Comment: @RichardFawcett That would over-complicate the badge awarding algorithm too much, because you couldn't then *just* look at the score, but you'd also have to look at the history of all votes for each post on a question. Too much effort for a silly bronze badge.

Comment: @animuson better change the short description than changing the algorithm.

Comment: @RichardFawcett , Aziz - [see my follow-up feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203178/164022) to change the description to reflect the algorithm