# Change the description of the revival badge to match the algorithm used to award it

Tags: feature-request, badge-description, revival-badge

The current description for the revival badge is:

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more

However, as per the discussion on [Revival Badge awarded incorrectly when other answer downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198572/164022) , the actual algorithm for awarding the badge is that it is given when your have the oldest answer with a score of 2 or more. An answer older than yours might have previously reached a score of 2 or more, but if, during a subsequent badge-bot run, the score on that older answer has dropped below 2, and your answer is at 2 or more, then you will then get the badge.

I propose the following wording:

> Answered more than 30 days later, and yours is the oldest answer that has a score of 2 or more